# python integrating code with raw_input timeout

Tags: python, timeout, python-2.7, raw-input

This is most of my code for my now working python blackjack game (or at least blackjack like game) I have now been told that I need to implement a time limit (user gets asked to input something and only has 3 or so seconds to give a response).

```
def deck():
        cards = range(1, 12)
        return choice(cards)


def dealer():
    total = deck() + deck()
    if total <= 15:
        totalf = total + deck()
        while totalf <= 21:
            return totalf
    if total > 15:
        return total

def player():
    card1 = deck()
    card2 = deck()
    hand = card1 + card2
    print "Cards dealt: %d and %d" % (card1, card2)
    while hand <= 21:
        choice = raw_input("Would you like to hit or stand?: ")
        print choice
        if choice == "hit":
            hand = hand + deck()
            print "Current Total: %d" % hand        
        elif choice == "stand": 
            return hand 

money = 100
highscore = 0

while money > 0:
    opp = dealer()
    me = player()
    if me > opp:
        highscore = highscore + 10
        money = money + 10
        print "Winner, winner, chicken dinner! You have $%d!" % money
        print "********************************************"
    elif opp > 21:
        highscore = highscore + 10
        money = money + 10
        print "Winner, winner, chicken dinner! You have $%d!" % money
        print "********************************************"
    elif me > 21:
        money = money - 20
        print "Bust! Dealer wins with %d. You have $%d reamaining." % (opp, money)      
        print "********************************************"
    elif opp > me:
        money = money - 20
        print "Dealer wins with %d. You have $%d reamaining." % (opp, money)
        print "********************************************"
    elif me == 21:
        highscore = highscore + 10
        money = money + 10
        print "Blackjack! You have $%d!" % money
        print "********************************************"
    sleep(1)    

print "Thank you for playing! Your highscore was $%d." % highscore
```

This is the code my professor has provided us with to do this:

```
   import sys, time
from select import select

import platform
if platform.system() == "Windows":
    import msvcrt

def input_with_timeout_sane(prompt, timeout, default):
    """Read an input from the user or timeout"""
    print prompt,
    sys.stdout.flush()
    rlist, _, _ = select([sys.stdin], [], [], timeout)
    if rlist:
        s = sys.stdin.readline().replace('\n','')
    else:
        s = default
        print s
    return s

def input_with_timeout_windows(prompt, timeout, default): 
    start_time = time.time()
    print prompt,
    sys.stdout.flush()
    input = ''
    while True:
        if msvcrt.kbhit():
            chr = msvcrt.getche()
            if ord(chr) == 13: # enter_key
                break
            elif ord(chr) >= 32: #space_char
                input += chr
        if len(input) == 0 and (time.time() - start_time) > timeout:
            break
    if len(input) > 0:
        return input
    else:
        return default

def input_with_timeout(prompt, timeout, default=''):
    if platform.system() == "Windows":
        return input_with_timeout_windows(prompt, timeout, default)
    else:
        return input_with_timeout_sane(prompt, timeout, default)
```

I am completely lost how to merge these two pieces of code. I've tried for the past couple hours to get it to work but for whatever reason its just not working. Any help would be amazing. (I apologize for the wall of code).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to call `input_with_timeout` function where you want the user's input.

In your player function:

```
def player():
    card1 = deck()
    card2 = deck()
    hand = card1 + card2
    print "Cards dealt: %d and %d" % (card1, card2)
    while hand <= 21:
        choice = input_with_timeout("Would you like to hit or stand?: ", 3, "stand")
        print choice
        if choice == "hit":
            hand = hand + deck()
            print "Current Total: %d" % hand        
        elif choice == "stand": 
            return hand
```

will prompt for an input, writing the "Would ... or stand" sentence before it. If the user do not answer before the timeout (in this case 3 second) the function will return "stand".

And be sure to include your professor's code in your main file.

Comment: I tried that but it now gives me an indentation error at:
    if choice == "hit": 
If I fix that than the timeout works but the code under that never runs.

Comment: Check if you have the same number of spaces before the `if choise == "hit"` statement and the line before. All of the line witch belongs to the same block have to be align. I copied your code and it worked on my computer.